# using numpy.Reshape python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

If you have an array,x, that is of shape [365,24,1] and you use

```
x = np.reshape(x,(8760))
```

and you have an identical array,y, but its shape is [24,365,1] and you use

```
y = np.reshape(y,(8760))
```

will you get the same array back out for x and y? or does it mix up the values differently?

Comment: did you try on small examples ?

Comment: How can `x` and `y` be identical if they have different shapes?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this out with a smaller toy example shall we? (Warning: I guess it really depends on what your actual `x` and `y` looks like though!)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)

In [3]: x
Out[3]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In [4]: y = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 6, 2)

In [5]: y
Out[5]:
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17],
        [18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])

In [6]: x2 = x.reshape(24)

In [7]: x2
Out[7]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

In [8]: y2 = y.reshape(24)

In [9]: y2
Out[9]:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

In [10]: x2 == y2
Out[10]:
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [11]:
```

This toy result shows the reshaped `x2` have same values as the reshaped `y2`. You will need to check what your actual input `x` and `y` look like though!